# Get the number of Requests in Express with Save

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I would like to know if is there any way of getting the total number of request in a certain path with Expressjs? But i need save On JSON like i want save data on JSON or TXT nothing more but i dont know how.

```js
let pingCount = "HERE I MUST ADD Some JS for save on TXT/JSON file and show data if you give request write on JSON +1"
app.get('/ping',(req, res) => {
  pingCount++;
  res.send(`ping world for ${pingCount} times`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from "fs";
app.get('/ping',(req, res) => {
    const pingCount = readFileSync("pingCount.txt");
    const newPingCount = parseInt(pingCount) + 1;
    writeFileSync("pingCount.txt", newPingCount.toString());
    res.send(`ping world for ${newPingCount} times`);
});
```

This should work, but create a pingCount.txt file with text `0` first-

Comment: This would work. Sadly, this is not efficient if it has multiple requests at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

use this one for this logic, First request = 1 Times and Second Request = 11 is add 1 on back not like 1+1 but like 1,1,1,1,1.

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync, existsSync } from "fs";
app.get('/ping',(req, res) => {
    let pingCount = '';
    if(existsSync("pingCount.txt"))
    {
      pingCount = readFileSync("pingCount.txt");
    }
    
    const newPingCount = `${pingCount} 1`;
    writeFileSync("pingCount.txt", newPingCount);
    res.send(`ping world for ${newPingCount} times`);
});
```